# extract xml element from database using sql query

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Hello I have the following xml structure within a database table column :

```
DECLARE @Response XML =

'<star:ShowInfo xmlns="http://www.starstandard.org/STAR/5" 
xmlns:ns2="http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/9" 
xmlns:star="http://www.starstandard.org/STAR/5" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" releaseID="5.1.5" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="">

<ShowDataArea>
    <ServiceInfo>
        <SVPlanInfo>
            <AKStatus>
                <Code>Error</Code>
                <STText xsi:type="ns2:TextType">E12143 - Please fetch me from this xml     </STText>
            </AKStatus>
        </SVPlanInfo>
    </ServiceInfo>
</ShowDataArea></star:ShowInfo>'
```

In the above xml I need to fetch the **STText** value which is 
**E12143 - Please fetch me from this xml**      . Can anyone point  me on how I can do it ?

I tried the following but it doesnt seem to work :

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' as xsd,
            'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' as xsi)
SELECT @Response.value('(/xsd:Response)[1]','nvarchar(500)') as ExceptionMessage
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What a pain.

remove:

```
xmlns="http://www.starstandard.org/STAR/5"
```

It is not a sql issue, but rather namespace-getting-confused issue.

Its heplful totake SQL out the equation sometimes, by testing some place like

http://xpath.online-toolz.com/tools/xpath-editor.php.